# TextView - Selected text pop up cut text below

Tags: android

I decided to add selected option in my TextView, but when it was selected and addition menu pop up - it cut TextView down below.
Before selection:

Before selection:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jbMN.png

After selection:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3XWh.png

How can I fix it?

activity_main:

````
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_yellow"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_date_field"
        style="@style/MainTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/selected_date_field" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_date"
        style="@style/SecondTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/selected_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/in_minutes_field"
        style="@style/MainTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/in_minutes_field" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/in_minutes_till_date"
        style="@style/SecondTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/in_minutes_till_date" />

</LinearLayout>```
````

Comment: try ```android:layout_width="wrap_content"``` to  ```android:layout_width="match_parent"``` or use padding

Answer (score 0):

you can try `app:autoSizeTextType:uniform` for that textView.
Note: If you gave already size like "textsize: 15sp" remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the problem was due to the fact that in the **themes.xml** I had the same color in `<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/blue</item>` (background) and `<item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue</item>` (color of handlers), because of it I couldn't see handlers

Thanks everyone!